# Trying to change a resource model on magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

sorry for this question, but I'm changing stuff around and getting a blank 
page almost every time, or no change at all!,

I'm trying to change the most viewed product:

```
<?php
  class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mostviewed extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract{
      public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        // get today and last 30 days time
        $today = time();
        $last = $today - (60*60*24*5);
        $from = date("Y-m-d", $last);
        $to = date("Y-m-d", $today);
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                ->addOrderedQty()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                ->addViewsCount()
                ->addViewsCount($from, $to);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')
            ->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);   
        $products->setPageSize(20)->setCurPage(1);
        $this->setProductCollection($products);
      }
  }
```

With an md featured filter (https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/md-featured-products.html?_ga=1.40864226.192476984.1462507802)

This one gives me the same results as the one before, it's like it doesn't get the eav

```
<?php
  class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mostviewed extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract{
      public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->addOrderedQty()
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('md_featured_product', 1)
                ->addViewsCount();
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')
            ->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);   
        $products->setPageSize(4)->setCurPage(1);
        $this->setProductCollection($products);
      }
  }
```

This is the original one from the md-featured-call:

```
       if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

                $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')
                        ->getProductAttributes();

                $collection->addAttributeToSelect($attributes)
                        ->addMinimalPrice()
                        ->addFinalPrice()
                        ->addTaxPercents()
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('md_featured_product', 1, 'left')
                        ->addStoreFilter();

                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($c$
                $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
```

I also tried changing

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
```

with:
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
and
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')

but got white screen on both cases,

I'm not sure what else to try :(, any help would be a lot of help

Comment: White screen means there's an error. You should enable Magento developer mode, and turn on error reporting so you can see what your errors are. Failing that (or as well) check your system and exception log files for errors.

Comment: it's activated, I will re-check the log files